# Can't Change Android Button Padding

Tags: android, button, padding

I have a table of buttons and am attempting to dynamically create and set the padding around the text of each with the following function:

```
public static void AddChartColBtn(TableRow row, String txt, String style) {
    Button note_chart_btn;
    note_chart_btn = new Button(ctx);
    note_chart_btn.setText(txt);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    note_chart_btn.setLayoutParams(params);
    row.addView(note_chart_btn);
}
```

I've tried working with LayoutParams classes to set margins and paddings, etc...but no matter what I try the button always fills the entire space of the current table cell, ignoring any padding. The Button class doesn't appear to have layout params, padding that can be manipulated directly. How can dynamically create and declare a button with 0 padding around it's text?

Answer (score 0):

set Both

```
params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
params.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
Button note_chart_btn;
note_chart_btn = new Button(ctx);
note_chart_btn.setText(txt);
note_chart_btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
note_chart_btn.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting something like this

android:padding="10dp" for every button you have in your layout in the .xml file of your layout

Answer (score 0):

`setPadding` should after the `setBackgroundResource`

Like this:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_bg)
button.setPadding(100, 0, 100, paddingBo0tom)
```